# Differentiate between unique constraint violations in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've created a Cosmos DB collection to store users. This collection has a Unique constraint on email addresses. The id for a user is a Guid. When I add a user to the collection, an exception with HttpStatusCode Conflict is thrown when the Guid already exists and also when the email address already exists. 
Is there a way to know which constraint caused the error?

The unique contraint is added like this:

```
myCollection.UniqueKeyPolicy = new UniqueKeyPolicy
{
    UniqueKeys =
    new Collection<UniqueKey>
    {
        new UniqueKey { Paths = new Collection<string> { "/EmailAddress/Address" }},
    }
};
```

The (expected) exception occurs after calling CreateDocumentAsync and I'm catching the exception like this:

```
catch (DocumentClientException e)
{
    if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
    {
        // I can't find anything in the Exception that indicates what constraint was violated
    }
}
```

e.Error contains:

```
{  
   "code":"Conflict",
   "message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Unique index constraint violation.\"]}\r\nActivityId: 3....6, Request URI: /apps/3....b/services/9....f/partitions/b....4/replicas/131903490859125028p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2018-12-27T15:56:06.4927341Z, Number of regions attempted: 1\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"
}
```

The reason I want to differentiate is so I can return a better message to the client. I know the Guid will normally be unique, but clients could call CreateDocumentAsync on an existing entity. Also, in another situation I might want multiple unique constraints on a collection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            catch ( Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException ex )
        {

           if ( ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict )
           {

              // Unique key constraint violation ...

           }
           else
           {

              // Some other issue ...
              throw;

           }
```

[How to check for unique key constraint violations / exceptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-dotnet/issues/612)

Update from the Product Group:

Currently we don’t expose sub status code to differentiate between Id conflict and unique conflict (or even more what kind of unique index this unique conflict is about). As was suggested, error message text can be used.

**Work around suggested:**

409 due to Unique Index constraint  violation sample:
{"code":"Conflict","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Unique index constraint violation.\"]} ... StatusCode: Conflict" ...}

409 due to duplicate id: 
{"code":"Conflict","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource with specified id or name already exists.\"]} ... StatusCode: Conflict" ...}

[image: Screen capture showing clarity for parsing text from exception.]

Comment: That is (almost) literally the code I have, but both the primary key (id) and the unique key (email) violation end up inside the if-statement. That makes sense because they *are* both unique key constraint violations, the question is, how to differentiate between them.

Comment: Let me look into this. I was thinking you didn't have the else {..} part. Let me reach out to the PG.

Comment: You could also use or include Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Error - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.documentclientexception.error?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I still have a pending question to the product group. I will enhance my answer when I have more information. Thank you!